# Can't see any drive to install linux on during installation

Tags: partitioning, mac, macosx

I am trying to install Linux Mint 19 on my 2017 Macbook Pro. I have bootcamp and a MacOS partition and I created a third one for Linux. Here's what my partitions look like:

[How I have my partitions formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY0LB.png)

Every time I boot Linux Mint from the flashdrive and click "install" all I can see is my 32gb flash drive. I cannot change disk/location and it shows the flash drive as the only available drive in GParted. Did I format something incorrectly?

Any isight it greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this? Having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to install a boot manager (e.g rEFIt); doing so, will make sure the additional partition you made is visible and therefore usable. Generally speaking, rEFIt is a better option for macs than the Bootcamp.